# Calculate Costs for Buildings

Tags: php, sql

I have the following arrays:

```
[costs] => Array (
   [0] => Array (
       [value] => 600
       [name] => Wood
   )
   [1] => Array (
       [value] => 200
       [name] => Stone
   )
   [2] => Array (
       [value] => 800
       [name] => Iron
   )
   [3] => Array (
       [value] => 300
       [name] => Gold
   )
)

Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [balance] => 70636.86
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [balance] => 70636.86
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [balance] => 70636.38
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [balance] => 141072.77
    )
)
```

I want to check if the second array enough resources to spend from the first array and if one of the values from the first array is not = or less. Can someone help me out?

What I've tried so far:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
{
    $balance = $this->listResources[$i]['balance'];
    if($balance >= $this->buildingCosts[$i]['value'])
        $this->listBuildings[$i][$this->listKey]['status'][$balance] = '1';
    else
        $this->listBuildings[$i][$this->listKey]['status'] = '0';
}
```

What I'm trying to find out is to see if I have enough resources in array to spend ( values that I need are found in costs )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is extremely cryptic (we can only vaguely guess, for example, that `$this->listKey` in some way refers to the building type you're trying to create, and some of your sentences are unintelligible), but I suspect you mean something like:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $balance = $this->listResources[$i]['balance'];
    $this->listBuildings[$this->listKey]['status'][$i] = ($balance >= $this->buildingCosts[$i]['value']);
}
```

That populates `$this->listBuildings` with status arrays that map resource index numbers to booleans indicating whether or not the available quantity of that resource is sufficient.

Comment: thanks it works, i was in a hurry when i posted this and very angry because it didn't work the way i wanted :-)